# why to use biases for every output element

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, xor

I have a problem on why there is a bias for every output element.
I knew only 1 bias for neuron output. Are there any advantages and disadvantages?

I have tried using a single bias for every output node. it gives me a slightly good result.

But when I used a bias for every output element it gave me a 98%+ accuracy.

I'm a little bit confused about how this actually works and does this work for any neural network?

Thank you!

```
import tensorflow as tf

import time

import numpy as np


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,2], name = 'X')

Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,1], name = 'Y')


W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2,2]), name = "W")

w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2,1]), name = "w")


c = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,2]), name = "c")

b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,1]), name = "b")


with tf.name_scope("hidden_layer") as scope:

    h = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W),c))


with tf.name_scope("output") as scope:

    y_estimated = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(h,w),b))


with tf.name_scope("loss") as scope:

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y_estimated, Y))


with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)


INPUT_XOR = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]

OUTPUT_XOR = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()


writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/xor_logs", sess.graph)


sess.run(init)


t_start = time.clock()

for epoch in range(100001):

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: INPUT_XOR, Y: OUTPUT_XOR})

    if epoch % 10000 == 0:

         print("_"*80)

         print('Epoch: ', epoch)

         print('   y_estimated: ')

         for element in sess.run(y_estimated, feed_dict={X: INPUT_XOR, Y: OUTPUT_XOR}):

         print('   loss: ', sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: INPUT_XOR, Y: OUTPUT_XOR}))

t_end = time.clock()

print("_"*80)

print('Elapsed time ', t_end - t_start)
```

'''

Comment: This is really simple example. Assume you have value x = 0 and y = 10. Whatever value of weights is > x*w, will always be 0... So how to get 10, with out any addition, which we call bias > x*w+b

Comment: @Stenga thank you for the answer. But the problem that I have is, why to use a bias for every x*w calculation. in the code the bias is a matrix other than a vector. I'm a little bit confused about why to use the bias as a matrix. Thank you.